# Data lost from .mdf file as I exit application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2, mdf

Recently I work on SQL Server 2008 R2 database. I create database and attach .mdf file of same database in my application with some default data in it . Run application default data coming properly. Now I insert, update some data in my application and its works fine. But as I exit application and again run application lastly added and updated data get lost but default data coming proper as earlier. Please help. Why new

Comment: are you commiting your changes to database before closing?

Comment: Just make sure you have one mdf file, It seems to me you are inserting and updating into other DB. :)

Comment: @Ehsan, Yes i am saving changes after every database operation. Its works fine if i connect to SQL server R2 on my local machine(By changing connection string in App.Config).

Comment: well i guess than we need to see your code.

Comment: I found answer to my que and add answer for same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mention by @Henk , @Microtechie , I scan my project folder and found there are 3 copies of .mdf file are there, 1st in project folder where code project([ProjectFolder ]) resides 2nd in [ProjectFolder]/bin/debug folder and 3rd in [ProjectFolder]/bin/release folder and suddenly solution to my que trigger in my mind. Problem not in multiple .mdf files in project folder, as I every time ‘Clean’ and ‘Build’ my solution new copy of .mdf file from [ProjectFolder] get copied into [ProjectFolder]/bin/debug folder, result in override of last .mdf file in same folder. Hence every time I build and run application only default data coming and last added and updated data get lost.
Thanku all for your replies and precise answer..!

Comment: Placed mdf file in different location from the project bin folder.

Answer (score -2):

What kind of object do you load your .mdf file data into? It is likely that you need to save the changes in that object before closing the application.

Comment: I used Entity Framework (.edmx). And every database statement is under 'using' store clause means as using scope end database connection get close. e.g
        `using(Mystore _store = new MyStore())
        {
         // Database operations
         _store.SaveChanges();
        }`