# Table not updating after inserting records using LINQ syntax

Tags: c#, database, linq, mdf

Here is my code first:

```
 DbHw10Ent de = new DbHw10Ent();

        Sales1 sal = new Sales1();

        sal.SalesAmount = 6900;
        sal.SalesDate = DateTime.Now;
        sal.TaxAmount = 100.00M;

        de.Sales1.Add(sal);
        de.SaveChanges();


        var sales = de.Sales1;

        foreach (var o in sales)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}--{1}--{2}--{3}", o.SalesID, o.SalesDate.ToShortDateString(), o.SalesAmount, o.TaxAmount);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Take note that it displays in the console but when I try to refresh my tables in the object explorer, nothing changes and when I close my solution, everything resets back to normal. Am I missing something here?
[image: this is my solution explorer]

NOTE: It seems that The updated database stays in the DEBUG folder in the bin/. What will I do to be able to update the database in the databse explorer as well!

Comment: Where is your database located, what kind of database is it. Maybe you have a local db file which is copied to `Debug` and `Release` folder.

Comment: it is a Service-based db

Comment: Looks file-based to me according to the picture... is there any build action associated with the DbHw10.mdf file?

Comment: right click on the database file (DbHw10.mdf ) and select "copy if newer"  for reference   (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)

Comment: dorry idk what is that

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444044/data-lost-from-mdf-file-as-i-exit-application or even better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why saving changes to a database fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147249/why-saving-changes-to-a-database-fails)

Comment: i did that........

Comment: What does it mean "everything resets back to normal?" Does it clear the database? Does it insert the missing record in the database? Does it recreates the database?

Comment: it does not show the record of what I have inserted programatically

Comment: Are connecting to the correct database in the code and looking at the same to verify the result? Can you,share the connection string used by the linq?